# how to dynamically change text in button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to change the text of a button with a click event, but am having trouble and have found no other solutions.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def buttonclick()
    oneButton["text"]="Bye"

OneButton = Button(root, text="hi", command = lambda: buttonclick()).grid (row=0, column =0, sticky=NSEW)

 root.mainloop()
```

With this method, I am getting:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

I have looked at `oneButton.config(text="bye")` and `oneButton.configure(text="Bye")` as well and with both. I learn that the button object does not have the attribute `config` or `configure`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using textvariable and stringvar().

```
 from Tkinter import *
 root=Tk()

 buttonText=StringVar()
 oneButton = Button(root, textvariable = buttonText, command = lambda: buttonText.set('bye')).grid (row=0, column =0, sticky=NSEW)
 buttonText.set('Hi')

 root.mainloop()
```